# Strapi does not update the content types on start

Tags: strapi

I have to deploy a strapi backend but I did not developed it.
After many tries, it is up and running in a kubernetes and connected to a postgres DB.

It seems ok as I can connect to the admin panel, but the content types created by the developer are not created in DB. In DB, I can't see any table other than Strapi's.
Can you confirm the DB is updated at stratup (and not on build) and tables are created based on src/api/**/schema.json ?

I tried to update to the latest Strapi (4.9.1) but I have the same problem.

Any idea why it is not working ?

When I try from a brand new strapi with sqlite, I can see the content types from an empty db.

I have to see the same with the real app.

Comment: I worked on this to find a solution. What I found:
1/ the build does not need to connect to the DB. The tables are created at startup. 
2/ BUT the build forlder is not enough, and you have to add the src folder in the final image / deployment because the schema.json are needed at startup to see the structures and create the tables in DB.